# PHP 5.3.10 global behaviour

Tags: global, php-5.3

I'm having trouble with a global variable, I think it might be pulling its data from a HTML Form Input, but I can't find any documentation on the web about global var pulling data from a HTML Form Input.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find a specific php 5.3 manual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227123/where-can-i-find-a-specific-php-5-3-manual)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a form is submitted the method tag specifies if it is a POST or GET request. Depending on what method your form is using your form values can either be in your $_POST or $_GET Super global.

Example:

`<form action="welcome.php" method="post">`

`Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>`

`E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>`

`<input type="submit">`

`</form>`

After the submit button on the form is clicked the form contents can be found by referencing the name attribute in the super global(In this case the POST).

`$_POST['name']`
`$_POST['email']`

For documentation see
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
This applies to PHP 4 >= 4.1.0, PHP 5, PHP 7 ie. fits PHP 5.3.

Comment: The thing is, I have a code here, where inside a function there is this line: global $login,$passwd, BUT this $login and $passwd does not exist anywhere beside the form inputs (name=login id=login and name=passwd and id=passwd), and this is working at our server (with PHP 5.3.10). That's why I asked about global behaviour...

Comment: I think I found it:
https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration54.incompatible.php
Says about register_globals it makes Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server as globals, that's why!